# Mountain Lion: Problem With Permissions

Tags: macos, permission

I recently tried compiling Textmate 2 now that it's open sourced. Followed all the directions [here](https://github.com/textmate/textmate)and downloaded all the dependencies. Now, when I tried to build (using ./configure && ninja) I received the following error:

```
make: *** [/Users/~/build/TextMate/Frameworks/SoftwareUpdate/fixtures/secret.pem] Error 1

[6/1169] Copy ‘"Frameworks/OakFoundation/src/NSString Additions.h"’…ninja: ERROR: mkdir(/Users/~/build/TextMate/include/OakFoundation): Permission denied

ninja: build stopped: .
```

Now, I figured that maybe Mountain Lion messed with permissions, so I gave it the ol' sudo try. I still receive a similar error -

```
rm /Users/jlvillalobos/build/TextMate/Frameworks/SoftwareUpdate/fixtures/secret.pem
[7/1169] Compile ‘Frameworks/scope/src/match.cc’…ninja: ERROR: mkdir(/Users/jlvillalobos/build/TextMate/Frameworks/scope): Permission denied
```

Now, I'm pretty stuck. I tried just checking my bash profile and I get a permission denied error on that too! I've ran "repair permissions" in disk utility for posterity and getting the same error. Anyone run into similar issues?

Comment: Where did you download the sources to (into which folder)? Did you set `builddir` manually? What is the output of `ls -al ~/.bashrc` and `id -a`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the first error message from make it seems as if the paths got configured wrongly by `configure`. So just rerun it and make sure to specify any required paths in full (without ~).

Answer (score 0):

When you're installing unix applications on MacOSX the installer needs to to be run as root.

Try typing

```
./configure && sudo ninja
```

or just

```
sudo ninja
```

given that you've already run configure.

All going well you should be prompted for your password (it won't print asterisks, just type the passowrd and press return.)

If this doesn't work it's probably because you don't have root enabled. Follow the instructions [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11331) to do that, then retry.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: *Never* `configure` or `make` as `root`, unless there is a very specific reason.

Second thing: In `make: *** [/Users/~/build/TextMate/Frameworks/SoftwareUpdate/fixtures/secret.pem] Error 1`: This `/Users/~/` looks HORRIBLY WRONG!

To change the ownership of the files back to you run

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/build/TextMate
```

Now do a

```
make clean && ./configure && make all && sudo make install
```

(`make install` is such an exception when you MIGHT want to use `sudo`.)